# Android: How can I protect my paid app from unregistered users?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am developing an Android app and I am going to sell it to a firm.

So, I will not use Google Play or other app stores like Amazon, etc...

How can I protect my app from other people?

Because we already made a deal with that firm.
That firm will use our app in only ten android devices.
I did not want to work our app on any other devices.

I researched about mac addresses to protect but I am not pretty sure.

Comment: You have a lot of ways. You can make a login interface with a login server or use Firebase Login to make it.

Comment: Only ten kinds of device . also you can check the device name .